# How to fake sms on Lollipop?

Tags: android, sms, android-5.0-lollipop

Here is a part of my code, but I don't understand why it doesn't work. I have the right permissions set in the manifest too.

```
enum Box
{
    Inbox, Sent
}

void AddMessage(String Address, String Message, Time Sent, Box b,
        boolean read)
{

    Uri u = null;

    switch (b)
    {
    case Inbox:
        u = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        break;
    case Sent:
        u = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
        break;
    }

    if (u != null)
    {
        Cursor mCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(u, null, null,
                null, null);

        ContentProviderClient P = this.getContentResolver()
                .acquireContentProviderClient(u);

        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put("body", Message);
        v.put("read", read);
        v.put("seen", true);
        v.put("address", Address);
        v.put("date", Sent.toMillis(false));
        v.put("date_sent", Sent.toMillis(false));

        try
        {
            int Thread = -1;
            Uri InsertedMessage = P.insert(u, v);
            Log.d("InsertedURI", InsertedMessage.toString());
            Cursor InsertedMessageCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
                    InsertedMessage, null, null, null, null);
            getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), v);
            if (InsertedMessageCursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                Thread = InsertedMessageCursor.getInt(InsertedMessageCursor
                        .getColumnIndex("thread_id"));
                Uri MessageThread = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/threadID/"
                        + Thread);
                Log.d("MessageThread", MessageThread.toString());
                Intent V = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                V.setData(MessageThread);
                this.startActivity(V);
            }

        } catch (RemoteException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

void processIntent(Intent intent)
{
    if (intent == null)
        return;

    if (Intent.ACTION_SENDTO.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        String destionationNumber = intent.getDataString();
        destionationNumber = URLDecoder.decode(destionationNumber);
        // clear the string
        destionationNumber = destionationNumber// .replace("-", "")
                .replace("smsto:", "").replace("sms:", "");
        editText_ToFrom.setText(destionationNumber);
    }

}
```

My problem is, that it does not put the sms in my sms list. I would like to achieve something like this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.neurondigital.FakeTextMessage
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the error message message that you are getting? Post the stacktrace

Comment: Okay so I figured out, it DOES work, but not on Lollipop. Does lollipop need some special permissions? Or the API part has been changed and it needs to be changed on my end too?